# Pandas series to array conversion is getting me arrays of array objects

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a Pandas series and here are two first two rows:

```
    X.head(2)
Which has 1D arrays for each row: the column header is mels_flatten
mels_flatten
0   [0.0171469795289, 0.0173154008662, 0.395695541...
1   [0.0471267533454, 0.0061760868171, 0.005647608...
```

I want to store the values in a single array to feed to a classifier model.

```
np.vstack(X.values)
or 
np.array(X.values)
```

both returns following

```
array([[ array([  1.71469795e-02,   1.73154009e-02,   3.95695542e-01, ...,
         2.35955651e-04,   8.64118460e-04,   7.74663408e-04])],
       [ array([ 0.04712675,  0.00617609,  0.00564761, ...,  0.00277199,
        0.00205229,  0.00043118])],
```

I am not sure how to process array of array objects.

My expected result is:

```
array([[  1.71469795e-02,   1.73154009e-02,   3.95695542e-01, ...,
         2.35955651e-04,   8.64118460e-04,   7.74663408e-04]],
       [ 0.04712675,  0.00617609,  0.00564761, ...,  0.00277199,
        0.00205229,  0.00043118]],
```

Have tried np.concatenate and np.resize as some other posts suggested with no luck.

Comment: Why do you have a list/array-valued series? Why don't you have a dataframe instead?

Comment: I am reading an Audio .wav file using Librosa library, which gives an array representation of Audio signal. My intent it to process the Audio signal in similar way MNIST hand written digit identification works. In case of MNIST the flat array contains 28x28 pixel info in arrays for each picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it likely that not all of your 1d arrays are the same length, i.e. your series is not compatible with a rectangular 2d array.

Consider the following dummy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
X = pd.Series([np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6])])
# 0    [1, 2, 3]
# 1    [4, 5, 6]
# dtype: object

np.vstack(X.values)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6]])
```

As the above demonstrate, a collection of 1d arrays (or lists) *of the same size* will be nicely stacked to a 2d array. Check the size of your arrays, and you'll probably find that there are some discrepancies:

```
>>> X.apply(len)
0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
```

If `X.apply(len).unique()` returns an array with more than 1 elements, you'll see the proof of the problem. In the above rectangular case:

```
>>> X.apply(len).unique()
array([3])
```

In a non-conforming example:

```
>>> Y = pd.Series([np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5])])
>>> np.array(Y.values)
array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5])], dtype=object)
>>> Y.apply(len).unique()
array([3, 2])
```

As you can see, the nested array result is coupled to the non-unique length of items inside the original array.

Comment: Thanks, I initially suspected that, but all the elements in the array is of same length: here is the  out put of  'X['mels_flatten'].apply(len).unique()'                      array([1536,    0])

Comment: @Spandan then you need to dig deeper. Are you sure all of them are 1d arrays? Use `.apply(np.shape)`: do you still get a single shape tuple?

Comment: @Spandan now I saw your edited comment....... How many unique elements do you think `array([1536, 0]) ` has? I can count 2. At least one of your rows contains a length-0 array/list.

Comment: for 'X['mels_flatten'].apply(np.shape).unique()'   I get following outcome:  'array([(1536,), (0,)], dtype=object)'  . Is there another way to get arrays from Series other than np.vstack, that you may recommend. Is there something easier to do if the values were stored in a list than array

Comment: @Spandan No! You just can't put arrays of different length into a 2d array. But there's good news: in your specific case the rows are either of a given length, or empty! So if you filter out the empty elements, it'll all work nicely and you'll get a 2d array. So in your case, `X = X[X.apply(len)>0]` will filter the original series, and stacking afterwards should work fine.

Comment: THANKS A BUNCH... Removing the 0 length array elements helped. Thanks for the guidance here .

Comment: @Spandan no worries, I'm glad we could work it out:)